# which layout should use for HCL U2?

Tags: android

Hi Friends please let me know which layout is suitable for HCL U2. I am using layout-sw600dp-tvdpi. which is not giving proper result. Please help as soon as. 
Thank you:

Comment: This may help you: http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The layout you are using layout-sw600dp* is suitable for HCL U2 if it is a 7 inch tablet. Hope this link helps [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14556800/layout-folders-for-google-nexus-7-and-10)

Comment: Thank you I am using layout-sw600dp-hdpi now its working fine

Answer (score 0):

- layout - Default layout
- layout-sw600dp - for 7" tablet (your HCL U2)
- layout-sw720dp - for 10" tablet