# What is Nexus 10 resource directory

Tags: android, android-layout, layout, nexus-10

**Please Read the question carefully before marking it as duplicate**
I have tried this SO [Layout folders for Google Nexus 7 and 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14556800/layout-folders-for-google-nexus-7-and-10), didn't worked for me.

I am developing an app which should work on both tabs and phones. I've created following resource directories:
`layout-mdpi`, `layout-hpdi`, `layout-xhdpi`, `layout-xxhdpi`, `layout-xxxhdpi`, `layout-sw600dp`, `layout-sw600dp-land`, `layout-sw600dp-land-tvdpi` (for nexus 7 land), `layout-sw600dp-tvdpi` (for nexus 7 portrait), `layout-sw800dp`, `layout-sw800dp-land`, `layout-sw720dp`, `layout-sw720dp-land`

**same for `drawable` and `values`

my problem is that in *Nexus 10* it always takes from `layout-xxxhdpi` (which is certainly not for tab) instead of `layout-sw720dp` and `layout-sw720dp-land`.

Is there any way to create a separate folder for nexus 10?

I already have tried these with no result:-

`layout-sw720dp-land-xhdpi`

`layout-sw720dp-xxhdpi`

Comment: That you need so many different layout directories indicates a deeper problem with the code. Especially the resolution dependent layouts are strange. It seems you are on the wrong track here.

Comment: @Henry If you think that I'm on the wrong track then can you please guide. My app has separate designs for tab and phone.

Comment: I don't know who has contributed the minus vote but can you please explain the reason?

Comment: That's hard without knowing any details. But if you specify measurements in dp there should be no need to have `layout-mdpi`, `layout-hpdi`, ... . Typically, maybe 4 different layouts should be enough (phone, phone landscape, tablets, tablets landscape).

Comment: @Henry for phone I have 5 different resolutions to support (no need for landscape). So I have 5 for phone

Comment: The layout itself can be the same on all resolutions if done correctly. Layout is mainly dependent on screen size and orientation. On the other hand drawables are typically dependent on resolution.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118866/discussion-between-rivu-chakraborty-and-henry).

Answer (score 0):

Possible solution is to go by screen size - `layout-large` and/or `layout-xlarge`.
Once I developed for highres tablets (10"), I had to go with `layout-large`.

Also you pretty much don't that number of directories, research about RelativeLayout, wrap_content, match_parent and density pixels

Comment: This one is old way... And google doesn't recommends that anymore.